# Add mail template parameters

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to add more parameter to the mail template.
I only found existing mail template parameter in this doc :
http://tharindue.blogspot.fr/2016/01/self-sign-up-for-user-accounts-with.html
which are :

- {first-name}
- {confirmation-code}
- {userstore-domain}
- {user-name}
- {tenant-domain}

These parameters should definitely be in WSO2IS doc.

Are there more parameters in the version 5.2 or 5.3 ?

I would like to have :
{last-name}, {user-id} and also claims values

Should I create a JIRA issue ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting all the user claims at email templates is done for the upcoming IS 5.3.0 release. You can refer the [JIRA here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4451) for more information. You can also checkout the latest milestone builds from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases) if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write a custom email notification sender. Found [this](https://wso2.org/jira/secure/attachment/43945/IncludeCustomAttributesinEmailTemplatesbyWritingaCustomEmailNotificationSenderforWSO2IdentityServer.pdf) on google. Have a look.